# Return a field from a function that returns a struct

Tags: matlab, function, struct

I'm using the function `dbstack` to get the name of the currently executing function. `dbstack` returns a struct, with three fields: `file`, `name` and `line`. I'm only interested in `name`. Is there any way of returning *just* the `name` field when I call the `dbstack` function, or do I need to use two lines (the following)?

```
thisFunction = dbstack;
thisFunctionName = thisFunction.name;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is the easiest (and propebly the best) way of doing what you want.

Alternatively, you can use `getfield`

```
>> thisFunctionName = getfield( dbstack, 'name' )
```